# Rails: Collect records whose join tables appear in two queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

There are three models that matter here: Objective, Student, and Seminar.  All are associated with has_and_belongs_to_many.

There is an ObjectiveStudent join model that includes columns "ready" and "points_all_time".  There is an ObjectiveSeminar join model that includes column "priority".

I need to collect all of the objectives that are associated with a given student and also with a given seminar.

They need to also be marked with a "priority" above zero in the seminar.  So I think I need this line:

```
obj_sems = ObjectiveSeminar.where(:seminar => given_seminar).where("priority > ?", 0)
```

Finally, they need to also be objectives where the student is ready, but has not scored above 7.  So I think I need this line:

```
obj_studs = ObjectiveStudent.where(:user => given_student, :ready => true).where("points_all_time <= ?", 7)
```

Is there a way to gather all the objectives whose join table records appear in both of the above queries?  Note that neither of the lists return objectives; they return objective_seminars, and objective_students, respectively.  My end goal is to collect the objectives that meet all of the above criteria.

Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Bonus question: I would also love to sort the objectives by their priority in the given seminar.  But I'm afraid that would add too much to the database load.  What are your thoughts on this?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get `Objectives` you'll need to start your query from that.
In order to query with an `AND` condition the associated tables, you'll need inner joins with these tables.
Finally you'll need a `distinct` operator to only fetch each objective once.

The extended version of what (I think) you need is:

```
Objective.joins(objective_seminars: :seminar, objective_student: :student).
  where(seminars: seminar_search_params, strudents: student_search_params).
  where('objective_seminars.priority > 0').
  where('objective_students.ready = 1 AND points_all_time <= 7').
  order('objective_seminars.priority ASC').
  distinct
```

Now for the database load it all depends on your indexes and the size of your tables.
The above query will translate to the following SQL (or something similar).

```
SELECT DISTINCT objectives.* FROM objectives
  INNER JOIN objective_students ON objective_students.objective_id = objectives.id
  INNER JOIN students ON students.id = objective_students.student_id
  INNER JOIN objective_seminars ON objective_seminars.objective_id = objectives.id
  INNER JOIN seminars ON seminars.id = objective_seminars.seminar_id
  WHERE seminars_query AND
    students_query AND
    objective_seminars.priority > 0 AND
    objective_students.ready = 1 AND points_all_time <= 7 AND
    objective_seminars.priority ASC
```

So you'll need to add or extend your indexes so that all 5 tables queries can have an index helping out. The actual index implementation is up to you and depends on your application's specific (read - write load, tables size, cardinality etc)

Comment: This helped me reach where I needed to be.  At first, I was getting an error that objective does not have a column "seminar".  But I was able to fix that by using quote syntax in all of the lines: where("objective_seminars.seminar_id == ?", seminar.id).  Thank you.